# css properties for a jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

How to add the following properties to a jquery ui dialog?

```
 background-color:white; filter:alpha(opacity=80); -moz-opacity: 0.8; opacity: 0.8
```

and the dialog properties are

```
 $bottombar = $(".bar", "#view").dialog({ height: 475, width: '100%', modal: false,
                                    draggable: false,maximize: false , stack: true, autoOpen:false, minHeight: 30,
                                    bgiframe: true ,title: "mytest" ,resizable: false, position: 'bottom',
                                    });
```

Or how to over ride the default background color of a ui dialog?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI uses the theme roller to generate custom CSS for it's controls.

Check out the documentation here:

http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming